# is it possible to use database connection in python pyramid tween?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I would prepare a tracking system for my application and check every request if it has a special value in the query parameter. In order to do that I created a tween and this tween checks for this special value and tries to update a specific object. In tween, everything looks ok, but when I check the same value at the view, the object looks not updated. Is it somehow possible to save this update?

```
def tracking_tween_factory(handler, registry):
    def tracking_tween(request):
        special_token = request.params.get('special_token')
        special_object = request.params.get('special_token')
        if special_token:
            request.dbsession.execute(
                    f"update {data['special_object']} set clicked = true where id = {data['special_token']}")

            # here was only for testing purposes just to check if this works
            tracked_object = request.dbsession.execute(
                    f"select * from {data['special_object']} where id = {data['special_token']}").fetchall()
            assert tracked_object[0].clicked is True  # value which should change
        return handler(request)
    return tracking_tween
```

Python 3.8
Framework Pyramid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution.

I had to setup my tween after pyramid_tm_tween.

so for example:

```
config.add_tween('coma.tweens.tracking_tween_factory', under='pyramid_tm.tm_tween_factory')
```

in my init file for pyramid configuration.